# How to catch messages from WebMethods Integration Server

Tags: soap, webmethods

I have to catch messages from WebMethods IS, put them into database and analyze them. I've stuck at the beginning, because I have no idea how to get xml file with message, that IntegrationServer is processing. Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone? I had an idea to set logging level for soap to TRACE, but i don't know if it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the "messages" you're talking about are the input documents of your service.

To transform documents into xml strings you can use the following built-in service:

```
pub.xml:documentToXMLString
```

Which is located in the built-in package: `WmPublic/pub/xml`

Below a screenshot of the built-in service in action:

[image]

The output xmldata pipeline field is the xml string that you will use to persist in your database.

Hope this helps!